# vim make delete operate as backspace

Tags: vim

I'm on a Ubuntu server, sshd in through my mac. The key on my keyboard above the `|` key is called `delete`, but it operates as `backspace` on my mac, deleting the character prior to the cursor. I have o press `control-delete` to get a delete that deletes the character *after* the cursor.

Before I fixed anything, hitting the `delete` key in insert mode (on the server via ssh) inserted `^?` into the text.

I read this site: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems
where I typed

```
:fixdel
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Into my .vimrc. But now my key acts as a `delete` key where pressing it deletes the character *after* the cursor, but I want it to delete the character *before* the cursor. How can I switch this functionality?

Essentially even though my key is physically called delete, it operates as backspace on my mac, and I want it to operate as backspace when using vim via ssh on a server.

Comment: What happens if you remove `:fixdel` and do `:inoremap ^? <backspace>` (here `^?` is where you type your `backspace`, it's not `^` followed by `?`)? Or leave `:fixdel` and do `:inoremap <delete> <backspace>` (this one will leave without real delete key)? This sounds like an easy problem and I'm basically wondering whether you've already tried the things from my questions.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @FDinoff $TERM prints xterm.

Comment: @xaizek setting vimrc to simply `:inoremap ^? <backspace>`, pushing backspace in insert mode inserts `^?` again.

Comment: @Tommy Terminal Emulator not TERM (iterm2 or terminal)?

Comment: @xaizek doing `:fixdel, :inoremap <delete> <backspace>` works! Moreover it does not leave me without delete because pushing control-delete then acts as delete, which is identical on my mac. On OSX, delete is backspace and control-delete is delete. Really they should change the paint on the actual key to say backspace. Please post as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @FDinoff I'm not sure how to answer your question, can you provide more info? You mean on my mac or in the SSH session? On my mac I'm using the normal "terminal" app but backspace there is fine without any modifications to vimrc.

Comment: @Tommy terminal is what I wanted to know. There is an option in the settings Preferences->Profile->Advanced under input that say Delete sends Control-H. Which you might want to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1

If you already have `:fixdel`, then you can instruct Vim to do interpret <kbd>Delete</kbd> as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in insert mode with this command:

```
:inoremap <delete> <backspace>
```

On some configurations this can remap all delete keys.

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, without `:fixdel`, that `^?` should be possible to remap too, like this:

```
:inoremap ^? <backspace>
```

Note that here `^?` is what appears when you type that "broken" key, it should be possible to enter it as a sequence of two keys, where the first one is a special "escape" key: <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd>. The effect should be the same, unless keyboard code is mangled somewhere in the middle (i.e. Vim gets invalid sequence on its input).

Comment: sorry, I just accepted this now; I thought the light blue +50 meant you already got it. For bounties, accepting an answer should reward it automatically.